# Putting a "resolve" on an angular-ui-router view isn't working - the page simply doesn't render

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-router

```
$stateProvider

.state('root', {
  url: '',
  views: {
    'root.base': { templateUrl: '/templates/root/root.html' },
    'root.sidebar': {
      templateUrl: '/templates/root/root-sidebar.html',
      controller: 'SomeDataController',
      resolve: {
        someData: function(DataService) { // DataService is an angular service for data retrieval
          return DataService.getDataList(); // returns an array
        }
      },
    }
  }
});
```

If I attempt to run a resolve on a subview with `angular-ui-router`, the page simply comes up blank. If I omit the resolve, it loads fine -- but I need to resolve for some data before my controller is instantiated. Do I have my syntax correct? I've searched for examples high and low but can't seem to find any that match my situation.

Given my above example, shouldn't the "root-sidebar.html" have the scope of "SomeDataController", and shouldn't SomeDataController have the data resolved in the route definition declared above?

Comment: Must be your DataService. Can you add the code for that?

Answer (score 1):

Your concept is working, maybe just some small settings are broken... I created [working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/xwNRqWaVtzGCOJozXs6R?p=preview)

Here is the controller consuming *someData*

```
  .controller('SomeDataController', function($scope, someData) {
    $scope.data = someData
  })
```

And here is our service loading some *JSON* and returning that as *async*:

```
  .factory('DataService', ['$http',
    function($http) {
      return {
        getDataList: function() {
          return $http
            .get("data.json")
            .then(function(response) {
              return response.data;
            });
        },
      };
    }
  ]);
```

The `state` defintion is unchanged *(just adjusted to display the data)*:

```
  $stateProvider
    .state('root', {
      url: '',
      views: {
        'root.base': {
          template: '<div>root base view</div>',
        },
        'root.sidebar': {
          template: '<div>root sidebar view' +
            '<h5>the resolve data</h5>' +
            '<pre>{{data | json}}</pre>' +
            '</div>',
          controller: 'SomeDataController',
          resolve: {
            someData: function(DataService) { // DataService is an angular service for data retrieval
              return DataService.getDataList(); // returns an array
            }
          },
        }
      }
    });
```

You can test that all [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/xwNRqWaVtzGCOJozXs6R?p=preview)